# Podio filter results missing external_id

Tags: podio

Items returned by `filter` have their `external_id` set to `null` for one of our apps. For example, running this:

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: OAuth2 [Token]' -d '{"limit":1}' 'https://api.podio.com/item/app/[App ID]/filter?fields=items.view(micro).fields(external_id)'`

Returns all the requested data for one app:

`{"filtered":119,"total":119,"items":[{"sharefile_vault_url":null,"title":"Title...","app_item_id":119,"link":"https:\/\/podio.com\/...","item_id":1234,"sharefile_vault_folder_id":null,"app_item_id_formatted":"VJD119","external_id":"share_1234","revision":0}]}`

The same request returns this for another app:

`{"filtered":138,"total":138,"items":[{"sharefile_vault_url":null,"title":"Title...","app_item_id":149,"link":"https:\/\/podio.com\/...","item_id":5678,"sharefile_vault_folder_id":null,"external_id":null,"revision":16}]}`

Do I need to configure anything in Podio to get it to provide an `external_id` for the items? The first app is just a copy of the second one so it shouldn't be configured differently.

I've redacted some of the returned data, let me know if any of that is needed to help debug. We're actually using the PHP library for this, but since directly calling the API as above has the same issue I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely items from your second app have no `external_id`, and that's why Podio API returns `null`.